# Is it correct to say

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Is it correct to say “i was surprised to learn your age”
Or “I was surprised when I learned your age was X/you were X years old "
If not can you explain why and propose an alternative that means more or less the same, thanks!

Comment: I would go with “I was surprised by your age”, but I am not certain if it sounds natural

Comment: "I was surprised to learn your age" sounds perfectly natural to me.  But in your other examples, the past tense only makes sense if you learned the age of the person some time ago, and they are now older than X.  If the person is still the same age, "I was surprised when I learned that you're X years old" is better than "... that you were X years old."

Answer (score 1):

In English, it's perfectly natural to ***be surprised to [verb] [X]***, but ONLY if *[verb]* somehow embodies the idea of *becoming **aware of** X* (for example, ***learn, see, hear, read, find, discover, notice,...***).

I'm not sure if this is a useful way of defining the "limits" of the usage, but it may help to note that no-one would be likely to say, for example, ***I was surprised to drink vodka***, even if he was in fact surprised (because he thought the glass he'd been offered contained *water*, and/or because up until that moment he considered himself to be a committed teetotaller). In such a context, *I was surprised to **find myself drinking vodka*** would be more likely.